# Shopware 6.3 - How to change domain name while transferring shop from one domain to another domain

Tags: shopware

I have website running on Shopware 6 under domain - http://www.mycurrentdomain.com

Now, I would like to transfer it into new domain - http://www.newfuturedomain.com

For now, I have copied **source code** and setup **Database** as well.

Does anyone know apart from this actions, do i need to perform any settings like db changes or apache settings (server changes)?

Comment: I'm just wondering why you copied the source-code and database?  Why not setup your new domain to point to the same hosting-setup?  And then setup in apache to forward your requests from old domain to newdomain with a 301 redirect.

Comment: Right. But where to change old domain in database. Domain pointing I already done. Adding forward to apache will increase redirection

Comment: You need to login on the admin-panel and go to the sales channel in question. There you can setup the right domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the Sales Channel Domain for your storefront to recognize, which sales channel to use for which domain.

You could technically change the entry in the sales_channel_domain table in your DB, but I highly recommend you to change this via administration gui, as stated before by @S.D.